# My updated runs the calculation but updates the same value into all rows

Tags: c#, sql

When I run the below function, it loops and writes the new values to the database, but the values are all the same. I had a similar issue, but I implemented it differently - this is a different way not using an array.

```
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
string end = @"SELECT balance, accrued FROM account ";
string update = @"UPDATE account SET balance = @balance WHERE account.prodid = product.prodid";
con.Open();
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(end, con);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    double balance = double.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
    double accrued = double.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
    balance = balance *accrued;
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand(update, con);        
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("balance", balance);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
}
```

Comment: What is `product` in your update sql statement? It doesn't even seem to be a valid sql statement.

Comment: @johnluke.laue the product is a table within the database

Comment: Do you want to update the whole account table or just a particular id?

Comment: @Jmeister copy your update statement, paste into SSMS, replace @ balance with 1, then try to run. It should fail: The multi-part identifier for product could not be bound...or something like that

Comment: I want to run the update so each calculation updates the balance the row is constantly on

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL directly to calculate your column balance as below.

```
UPDATE account SET balance = balance * accrued
```

Best Regards .